# Getting row data of inserted row (Mysql, PHP, mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to get back the postid (auto-incrementing PK) of a row when i insert it.

I am currently using this to get it

```
//get postid to return
if($result = $db -> query('SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE title = \''.$title.'\' LIMIT 1')){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $json['postid']  = $row['postid'];
        $result->free();
```

where $title is the title name of the newly-inserted post.

Is there part of the mysqli class that will allow me to do this in one query?? Does $db -> query() return any information that will make this simpler and more secure?

I have tried looking through the mysqli documentation, but I could not find what i wanted. I'm sure it is there somewhere.

Multiple titles will screw this up, and although they are not allowed, you cant be too safe

Comment: You do realize your query is vulnerable to SQL injection because you're not escaping $title, and it doesn't matter how safe you think $title is, it's not.

Comment: $title was escaped beforehand because it was used in the INSERT query before this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does your table have an AUTO_INCREMENT column? If so you can use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) or [`mysqli->insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get that value, and then use it to select the row. [More info here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/getting-unique-id.html).

Comment: or you can write a query to get the id yourself and then put it in the inserted data.

Comment: Arthur: That's true, but there's always a chance that another client will be trying to do the same thing at the same time and you'll end up with a collision.

Comment: Jordan: Thank you very much, works perfect. I had seen this method, but did understand know how worked. TY!

Comment: Jordan: If the query is `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` then it's safe. The value is stored/returned per session.

Comment: Jordan:  I do not use mysql so I am not sure but hopefully it doesn't work like that.  The postgresql serial (autonumber) ensures each number is unique no matter what.  But I dunno about mysql :)

Comment: @Jordan could you please provide a snippet, I am struggling with how to use mysqli->insert_id to select the affected row. I am getting the integer result of mysqli->insert_id but can't figure out how to use it to select the affected rows

Comment: @Jordan is this how? $last_id = $conn->insert_id; $sql_last_id = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $conn->insert_id=$last_id LIMIT 1";
 $result = $conn->query($sql_last_id);  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "field1: " . $row["field1"]. " - field2: " . $row["field2"]. " " . $row["field3"]. $last_id . "<br>";
  }
 
 } 
 else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql_last_id . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 } Here only the error is the wrong row is output

Answer (score 3):

insert_id
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: could you please provide a snippet, I am struggling with how to use mysqli->insert_id to select the affected row. I am getting the integer result of mysqli->insert_id but can't figure out how to use it to select the affected rows

Comment: is this how? $last_id = $conn->insert_id; $sql_last_id = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $conn->insert_id=$last_id LIMIT 1"; $result = $conn->query($sql_last_id); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "field1: " . $row["field1"]. " - field2: " . $row["field2"]. " " . $row["field3"]. $last_id . "<br>"; } } else { echo "Error: " . $sql_last_id . "<br>" . $conn->error; } Here only the error is the wrong row is output