# after submit, echo mysql id of user

Tags: php, mysql, submit, echo, auto-increment

I have a bit of a problem and i'm really sorry to bug you but i've looked a lot and can't find a good answer. When a user submits on my page the data goes to me mysql server and gets stored and mysql gives it an auto_increment id. When the user submits, i want the id that mysql assigns to their submission to be echoed. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect('host','username','pass','db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO subusers (username, date, ip)
VALUES
('$_POST[username]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[ip]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added", mysql_insert_id();
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

thats the code that send their data to the server, when it does and gets an id from the server i want it to echo the id.

Comment: Try to use `mysqli->insert_id`. This is probably a duplicate for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929504/getting-row-data-of-inserted-row-mysql-php-mysqli

Comment: can you please explain how/where to put it in my code? i'm sorry i'm a bit of a noob :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` syntax.

You should replace `mysql_insert_id()` in your code with [`mysqli_insert_id($con)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Now you should have the correct count.

Apart from that you have an sql injection problem. You should switch to prepared statements with bound variables instead of injecting your `$_POST` variables directly in your query.

Comment: it does not work. when i test it says: Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: @user2356634 Check the link to the manual; You need to add `$con` as a parameter like you did everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mysql_insert_id](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id) or [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) (for more recent versions of PHP).

eg.
`echo mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: can you please explain how/where to put it in my code? i'm sorry i'm a bit of a noob :/

Answer (score 0):

The php function

```
mysql_insert_id()
mysqli_insert_id()
```

will return the primary key of the last row inserted.

Comment: can you please explain how/where to put it in my code? i'm sorry i'm a bit of a noob :/

Comment: That's already there and it's not working as the OP is using mysqli.